# Servidor MySQL não consegue iniciar no CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos

Não consigo efetuar nenhuma operação no MySQL pois dá erro de:

> Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server

```
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql status
MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql[FAILED]
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 301: cd: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory
Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server (/usr/local/mysql/[FAILED]ld_safe)
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql start
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 301: cd: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory
Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server (/usr/local/mysql/[FAILED]ld_safe)
root@server2 [~]# mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

Arquivo `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
root@server2 [~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
user = mysql
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_connections = 500
max_user_connections = 35
wait_timeout=40
connect_timeout=10
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_concurrency = 8
server-id       = 1
skip-innodb

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Pesquisando em alguns posts, encontrei que algum programa pode estar prendendo o MySQL. Segue o comando que verifiquei:

```
root@server2 [~]# lsof | grep mysql
tailwatch 20718      root  mem       REG        3,5    206553    8922204 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/i386-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
```

E o comando `yum info mysql-server`:

```
root@server2 [~]# yum info mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.com
 * extras: centos.chi.host-engine.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Outras informações:

- não existe nenhum processo do MySQL rodando.
- CentOS versão 5.10 (Final).
- É um server dedicado mantido pela hostdime. Desde quando foi instalado só precisei alterar pacotes uma vez, que foi para a atualização do PHP. E não teve problema nenhum. Isso tem quase 7 meses.
- Nunca houve necessidade de atualização a não ser para o PHP (como já disse, há 7 meses). Fora isso nunca houve necessidade de atualizar MySQL com periodicidade.

Comment: Provavelmente é simples: o **servidor** MySQL não está rodando na máquina, portanto você não tem como executar o **cliente** `mysql`. Já tentou dar um `service mysqld start` antes de tentar usar o `mysql`?

Comment: Notório. Mas não consigo efetuar nada. E estou com medo pois tenho 2 bases imensas e nem o mysqldump funciona.

Comment: service mysqld start - mysqld: unrecognized service

Comment: O server funciona normalmente a 2 anos. Com certeza tinha ambos serviços instalados.

Comment: Em todo o caso, `yum info mysql-server` só pra ver. Seria legal vc dar mais detalhes do que mudou na máquina pra ela parar.

Comment: @Bacco atualizei o post com a saida

Comment: Qual a versão do CentOS?

Comment: CentOS release 5.10 (Final)

Comment: Muito estranho, pq no 5.10 o nome do pacote é mysql-server mesmo. Andou mexendo nos repositórios?

Comment: Então.. É um server dedicado mantido pela hostdime. Desde quando foi instalado só precisei alterar pacotes uma vez, que foi para a atualização do php. E não teve problema nenhum. Isso tem quase 7 meses.

Comment: Não sei muito por onde vc vai ter que começar aí, pq realmente está estranho. Vc mantem ele atualizado sempre? O serviço funcionava e parou de bobeira?

Comment: Nunca houve necessidade de atualização a não ser para o php. Como já disse, ha 7 meses. Fora isso nunca houve necessidade de atualizar mysql com periodicidade.

Comment: Acho que nesse caso aí a primeira coisa a fazer é baixar os diretórios da base de dados e ver se está tudo ok, pq parece que o problema é mais sério. E manter servidor atualizado é bom pra evitar dor de cabeça com riscos de segurança. Se foi feita a instalação padrão, o caminho é `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: Valeu @Bacco. Irei fazer esse backup para evitar perda de dados.

Comment: Esta pergunta [está sendo discutida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/porque-%c3%a9-que-esta-pergunta-esta-a-ser-fechada)

Answer (score 1):

O seu sistema parece ter sofrido um crash (não desligado da forma correta), e por consequência, não deve ter apagado o arquivo de lock do mysql server em um procedimento normal de shutdown.

Apague o arquivo de lock com o comando abaixo:

```
rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql
```

Rode de novo o `/etc/init.d/mysql status`.

ps: eu estou usando RHEL5, o arquivo de lock é ligeiramente diferente: `/var/lock/subsys/mysqld`